# Is it possible to make a heliostat with no moving parts?

Tags: solar

I want to place a couple of mirrors outside the house to direct some sunlight to the windows, which will make it easier to cope with the soul-crushing overcast winters here in Melbourne, Australia.

In order to remain focused on a window, the position of the mirror would have to change to compensate for the change in the sun's position in the sky. One of the options is building a heliostat - a tracking system that employs a 2-axis control mechanism to rotate/shift the mirror. There are in fact commercial systems available to do exactly what I need - for example Sunflower Heliostat, that is $299.

I would like, however, to produce a more economic solution with no moving parts. One of the options is to build a long, concave mirror with a profile that takes into account the sun's position. Something like this:

[image]

On the surface it looks like a doable task, although I just wanted to check if I am missing something very obvious and my plan is doomed.

Comment: Make sure the surface finish is akin to brushed aluminum. If it has a polish and anything falls in the focus, you will find you've underestimated how much solar energy you can capture with this.

Comment: All this is doing is increasing the square footage of mirror you are using to compensate for lack of motion.

Comment: Re focusing solar energy: https://www.nesfa.org/about/history/janes-skylark/

Comment: Using reflectors to brighten a home is common.  I think 'heliostat' and 'focus' imply more precion than is usually needed in these circumstances.  Sunlight is basically free, in human eyeball quantities, so it's entirely fine if some of the light coming off the reflector doesn't make it through the window.  I wouldn't even call it waste.  'Espaciel' sells products that might inspire you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no.

You might be able to produce a curve that will reflect an arc (spanning the days extent from east to west) all day on a given day without moving it, but only a small portion of such a mirror will be going into your window at a given time, wasting the rest of its arc.  Further, (as the season changes) your north-south alignment has to change, although this change is much slower.

A concave (focusing) mirror will have to be aimed to achieve concentration. Its focal length is a function of its curvature.   You can simplify your control to 1 axis by using a polar mount.

Have a look at some of the [Heliostat sites](http://www.green-life-innovators.org/tiki-index.php?page=Sunalign)

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that 2-axis shifting isn't there for nothing...

Answer (score 1):

This amazing free tool allows experimenting with any combination and shape of mirrors and lens:

https://phydemo.app/ray-optics/simulator/

[image]

[image]

I am experimenting with parabolic mirros, circular mirros, custom-curved mirrors, and the same with lenses... but this is hard!

A little anti-intuitive, but it looks that a convex circular mirror could keep the sun reflected on a target for all along the day:

[image: sunrise]

[image: sunset]

The smaller is the curvatire radius of the mirror, the longer time sun rays stay on target:

[image]

[image]

But of course the longer they stay, the less dense they are (hence less light).

I think the design of this static heliostat is based on two different curvatures: little curvature to have a broad strip all along the wall, and a big curvature to make the strip thin:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The arc of light spilling onto surfaces other than the window demonstrates the  problem with this approach, as mentioned in another answer: only a narrow band if that mirror is actually doing what you want it to do at any given time. Whether that's enough to justify the cost depends on your needs and location. You can make the mirror bigger to compensate, but that drives up cost.

Comment: not exactly, you can have a small mirror which fills your whole window, although with reduced light intensity. Anyway I am trying a combination of mirrors and lenses to keep the sun focused on an area while sun moves (still no luck, but I am proceeding totally randomly).

Comment: The more of the sky you try to cover, the less light you will gather from any one point in the sky and/or the less of the room you'll be projecting that light onto. That's sorta unavoidable no matter what passive  optics you use.  Nothing wrong with experimenting; I can't see how but you might find a way to prove me wrong. Just be aware that the problem with random experimentation is that you go down a lot of dead-end roads, which can be expensive and doesn't guarantee a solution is possible. Good luck...

Comment: it just came to my mind an image I've found some years ago... https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Claudio-Pernechele/publication/347699394/figure/fig1/AS:1017227004350466@1619537225704/Optical-layout-of-the-fisheye-lens.png  I wonder if I will be ever able to simulate such optics!